# Error in writing own system call: incompatible type for argument 2 of `copyout'

Tags: c, system-calls, bsd

I am writing my own system call in openBSD. I am trying to use the copyout function which has the signature :

```
 int
     copyout(void *kaddr, void *uaddr, size_t len);
```

I have an array

```
char word[MAX_STR_LENGTH+1];
```

I also have a struct

```
 struct sys_<name of the function>_args *uap
```

The struct is declared as the following:

```
struct sys_<name of function >_args {
    syscallarg(char *) text;
};
```

I am getting an incompatible type for argument 2 of `copyout` when I try to use the copyout function like this:

```
copyout(word, uap->text, sizeof (word));
```

Here is the error message:

```
 In function <name of function>
 incompatible type for argument 2 of `copyout'
*** Error code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the _actual_ error message?

Comment: And the struct declaration of uap?

Comment: That's only part of the error message.

Comment: The struct isn't declared anywhere. When you are passing variables from user space to kernel space it gets created.

Comment: If  `uap->text` is indeed a `char *`, it doesn't match the expected `void *`, but that shouldn't be an issue, right?

Comment: What exactly is `sys_<name of the function>_args`?

Comment: The name of the struct is sys_ followed by the name of the function _ args

Comment: Yes, but it has to be declared somewhere. What is that declaration?

Comment: I don't know where it is. I'll try to find it.

Comment: I get the following message "union has no member named `datum'"

Comment: I've seen examples where the copyout function is used in openbsd just like I'm using it right now.

Comment: I'll make a bet in those examples the parameter being passed is not wrapped in a syscallarg union. There seems to be a macro to help out too. SCARG. Does this work `copyout(word, SCARG(uap,text), sizeof (word));` . The macro SCARG apparently accounts for little and big endian automatically. This [link](http://www.phrack.org/archives/issues/60/6.txt) show some uses of SCARG with _copyin_

Comment: @MichaelPetch it compiles but it gives me an error when I run it: Memory fault (core dumped)

Comment: For both of those examples you mentioned

Comment: I updated my comment with a link that uses SCARG with copyin. The reason your original question failed to compile is that the second parameter was actually a union containing your char *, not your actual char *. The C compiler can't convert a union to a void *. As to the memory problem it may be related to another bug in your code.

Comment: As an idea for your segfault. What happens if you define and initialize _word_ as `char *word = (char *) malloc(MAX_STR_LENGTH+1);` . I'm wondering if a variable located on the stack (as `char word[MAX_STR_LENGTH+1];` might if defined in a function) causes an issue. Try using a malloc'ed region instead. I'm just guessing since I haven't done kernel work with BSD.

Comment: The struct is defined and made by the kernel so I have no control over how it is defined.

Comment: I'm not asking you to change the struct. Asking you to try changing how you create your _word_ array to see if the segfault issue is resolved.

Comment: Regular malloc doesn't work in kernel space